# Out Of Memory when passing selected images from phone storage

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

I'm creating an app in which you store information about clients in your phone. I also store bitmap locations to a database that when loaded are thumbnail size in a `GridView` when viewing the clients information.

To select the images another `Activity` will start where they can scroll and select which images they would like, with a maximum of 6 images.

However, after scrolling through a full page and selecting 6 images to pass to the client `Activity`, I experience an `Out Of Memory Exception`. How can I clear the memory before starting my next `Activity`?

Here's my `Activity` in which they select up to 6 images

```
public class CustomGalleryActivity extends Activity {

    private GridView grdImages;
    private Button btnSelect;
    private GalleryImageAdapter imageAdapter;
    private String[] arrPath;
    private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
    private int ids[];
    private int count;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_gallery);
        grdImages= (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grdImages);
        btnSelect= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelect);

        final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null, null, orderBy);
        int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
        this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
        this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
        ids = new int[count];
        this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.count];

        for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
            imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
            ids[i] = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
            int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            arrPath[i] = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
        }

        imageAdapter = new GalleryImageAdapter();
        grdImages.setAdapter((ListAdapter) imageAdapter);
        imagecursor.close();

        btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectOnClick();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    /**
     * This method used to set bitmap.
     * @param iv represented ImageView
     * @param id represented id
     */
    private void setBitmap(final ImageView iv, final int id) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
                return MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                iv.setImageBitmap(result);
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    public class GalleryImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public GalleryImageAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return count;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_gallery_item, null);
                holder.imgThumb = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgThumb);
                holder.chkImage = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkImage);

                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.chkImage.setId(position);
            holder.imgThumb.setId(position);
            holder.chkImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    int id = cb.getId();
                    if (thumbnailsselection[id]) {
                        cb.setChecked(false);
                        thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                    } else {
                        cb.setChecked(true);
                        thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                    }
                }
            });

            holder.imgThumb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int id = holder.chkImage.getId();
                    if (thumbnailsselection[id]) {
                        holder.chkImage.setChecked(false);
                        thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                    } else {
                        holder.chkImage.setChecked(true);
                        thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                    }
                }
            });


            try {
                setBitmap(holder.imgThumb, ids[position]);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
            }
            holder.chkImage.setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]);
            holder.id = position;
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imgThumb;
        CheckBox chkImage;
        int id;
    }

    public void selectOnClick() {
        final int len = thumbnailsselection.length;
        int cnt = 0;
        int i;
        String selectImages = "";

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (thumbnailsselection[i]) {
                cnt++;
                selectImages = selectImages + arrPath[i] + "|";
            }
        }

        if (cnt < 6) {
            for(i = cnt; i < 6; i++) {
                selectImages = selectImages + "blank" + "|";
            }
        }

        if (cnt == 0 ) {
            selectImages = "blank|blank|blank|blank|blank|blank|";
        }

        if (cnt > 6) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please only select 6 images.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            Log.d("SelectedImages", selectImages);
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("data", selectImages);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any input or advice!

To clarify, I can select 6 images just fine without the OOM exception, but as soon as I scroll through the first page or more I experience the OOM exception.

Comment: Why don't you use picasso or any other image loading library?

Comment: i guess ive never tried. never used a library in android studio before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) for loading images in your `GridView` instead of the `AsyncTask` you're using in the `setBitmap` function.

To add Glide in your code, you need to add the following in your `build.gradle` file.

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral() // jcenter() works as well because it pulls from Maven Central
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0-RC0'
}
```

Then you need to convert your `BitMap` to `ByteArray` and then modify your `setBitmap` function like this.

```
private void setBitmap(final ImageView iv, final int id) {
    byte[] byteArray = 
        bitmapToByte(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);

    Glide.with(this).load(byteArray.asBitmap().into(iv);
}

private byte[] bitmapToByte(Bitmap bitmap){
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    return byteArray;
}
```

Comment: i've been thinking about this because i haven't had time to try it. But how would i apply this to a gridview?

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question. You've already load images in your items of your `GridView`. I just have modified your `setBitMap` function.

Comment: Yea i got it all working I realized what you did after I read into it more. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to know that helped.